# Creating two attachments in a single chatter feed item. Is that possible?

Tags: chatter, canvas, feeditem

I am trying to create a chatter feed item through batch process which would have two attachments.

1. Canvas
2. PDF file

In the documentation the attachment parameter for the method, `ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem` seems to be accepting single attachments. Is there any workaround for this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently, feed items can only have a single attachment. One workaround would be to post the Canvas attachment in a feed item, and then to attach the PDF file in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One can use **Chatter Rest Api** which provides the ability to attach more than one attachment.

Kindly refer the link for better reference.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_element_content.htm